# Can I find such a intelligent function to deal with all query conditions in database

Tags: database

If we want to query something in database, we can use where conditions, such as select * from user where id=1;
I can define a function :

```cs
bool query(int id,string tableName)
{
  database.id.equalTo(id);
}
```

if I want to find the user less than 18(age) years old:

```
bool query(int age,string tableName)
{
  database.age.lessthan(age);
}
```

so for two conditions we have two function relative.

Can I find such a way ,that

```
bool query(string condition)
{
database.find(condition);
//it will deal with the condition intelligent use the required function.
}
```

I know database can read sql syntax. But I want to find the function that can provide developer a convenient way without writing the sql syntax, just pass the condition sentence that: age<18, id=1. And the function return the result1.When enter arg>19 the function return the result2.
I am not sure if I have mention my problem clearly. Seeking for help!

Comment: That's what LINQ is meant to achieve in .Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For PHP you can use Doctrine ORM. Doctrine 2 is an object-relational mapper (ORM) for PHP 5.4+ that provides transparent persistence for PHP objects.

The 'where' clause should do what you need.

> http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html#high-level-api-methods

Similar QueryBuilders exist in other languages. No need to reinvent the wheel.

> http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html